# Вывод уровня сигнала Wi-Fi

Tags: android, gui, wifi

Нашёл я, значит, на просторах [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18831442/how-to-get-signal-strength-of-connected-wifi-android) инструкцию по получению сигнала Wi-Fi. Код из вопроса работает только на эмуляторе (на физическом устройстве Android 4.4.2 не работает).

Но если я убираю проверку

```
if(result.BSSID.equals(wifi.getConnectionInfo().getBSSID()))
```

то всё работает, но `tv.setText` только добавляет строчки, а не обновляет их (на эмуляторе обновляет). Я пробовал использовать код из ответа, но он тоже не работает.

В чём кроется проблема?

```
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    int state = wifi.getWifiState();
    if(state == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED) {
        List<ScanResult> results = wifi.getScanResults();

        for (ScanResult result : results) {
            if(result.BSSID.equals(wifi.getConnectionInfo().getBSSID())) {
                int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(wifi.getConnectionInfo().getRssi(),
                        result.level);
                int difference = level * 100 / result.level;
                int signalStrangth= 0;
                if(difference >= 100)
                    signalStrangth = 4;
                else if(difference >= 75)
                    signalStrangth = 3;
                else if(difference >= 50)
                    signalStrangth = 2;
                else if(difference >= 25)
                    signalStrangth = 1;
                tv.setText(tv.getText() + "\nDifference :" + difference + " signal state:" + signalStrangth);
            }
        }
    }
}
}, new IntentFilter(WifiManager.RSSI_CHANGED_ACTION));
```

Comment: добавь код в вопрос, чтобы можно было от чего-то отталкиваться

Comment: @Александр добавил

Comment: а в манифесте все `permissions` добавлены?

Comment: @Александр да, конечно. Иначе весь код бы не работал, а так только if не работает.

Comment: код из ответа по ссылке, который отмечен как правильный ответ, тоже не работает?

Comment: @Александр верно, не работает.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#calculateSignalLevel%28int,%20int%29

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33851/discussion-between-sergey-molyak-and-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос:

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);

// Level of a Scan Result
List<ScanResult> wifiList = wifiManager.getScanResults();
for (ScanResult scanResult : wifiList) {
    int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(scanResult.level, 5);
    System.out.println("Level is " + level + " out of 5");
}

// Level of current connection
int rssi = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo().getRssi();
int level = WifiManager.calculateSignalLevel(rssi, 5);
System.out.println("Level is " + level + " out of 5");
```